# Can I uniquely identify an *installation* without violating Apple ToS?

Tags: ios-appstore

If [Apple discourages uniquely identifying an iOS device](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/70991) I would wonder how would push notifications work?  Won't you need that ID to uniquely send to the device?

Though I am not really after uniquely identifying the device, more that I can use something that's specific on the device or installation (like the push token) to identify the running application for

1. diagnostics
2. request integrity (ensuring that the request came from the device and not somewhere else, though I know that can easily be spoofed if you get rid of the device as the attack source)

Comment: What do you mean by "request integrity" exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way push notifications work is that the app requests permission from the user for notifications, when granted, it requests a device token. The device token is sent to and stored on the server(s) backing the app. Whenever the servers needs to send a push notification to that particular app, they give the device token to Apple's push notification service in order to identify that particular app on that particular device.

Similarly you app or backend server can generate an identifier that is stored on the phone to identify that particular app installation on that particular device.

Note of this violates any Apple "ToS".